Java docker-compose permission denied in WSL Docker setup
I got a weird setup where I can't build the java image in wsl docker setup but I can do it in Windows Docker setup. The error is permission denied: unknown. I read that I need to add chmod +x file.sh inside dockerfile but still the same error. Problem is I can build the docker image in Windows Docker even without the chmod inside dockerfile
structure
.
├── docker
│   ├── nginx
│   │   └── conf.d
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── entrypoint.sh
├── project
└── docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp-app
    # restart: always
    build: ./docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/project:cached
      - ./docker/entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh:cached
      - ./.m2:/root/.m2

   ... other setup not related

Dockerfile
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache bash procps curl tar

# common for all images
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

COPY --from=maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-11 ${MAVEN_HOME} ${MAVEN_HOME}
COPY --from=maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-11 /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY --from=maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-11 /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml

RUN ln -s ${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.9.5
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
# ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

# WORKDIR
WORKDIR /var/www/project

#Start application
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"] # the chmod command recommended.
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD [""]

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/sh
# You can set here anything you need before starting the spring boot application

clear
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
while true; do
    sleep 1
done

Error stacktrace
ERROR: for myapp-app  Cannot start service app: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
make: *** [Makefile:4: up] Error 1


Explanation
      - ./docker/entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh:cached

Your chmod +x does not have any effect, since you later override the file with a bind mount. If that file does not have executable flag (x) locally, it will not have it in the container.
In fact, I think your Dockerfile will not build at all in it's current state, since the entrypoint.sh does not seem to be available in the image:
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

Solutions
Option 1: Copy the entrypoint to the image first
...
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

And also remove the bind mount from your docker-compose.yml
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/project
      - ./.m2:/root/.m2

Option 2: If possible, set the permissions already on the local machine
I did not quite catch how exactly is your system setup, so be warned that this won't work directly on Windows, but might work inside WSL (check chmod WSL (Bash) doesn't work this if it does not).
Anyway, you can set the file permissions to executable before mounting, so inside WSL run chmod +x ./docker/entrypoint.sh
With that, you can keep the bind mount and remove the faulty RUN-instruction from your Dockerfile.
This solution also can enhance the Option 1: you don't need the RUN chmod +x ... part with that solution either then.
